# Package Interfaces - Coupling & Re-Usability

Tags: interfaces, code-reuse, dependencies, packages, coupling

## Intent

Packages should be designed to perform a single function well.

Ideally this means that they should be highly modular and different packages should be able to be 'plugged-in' simply by ensuring that they share a common interface.

However, I'm unsure how to do this without creating some kind of dependency between the packages or creating ugly 'integration classes' or a 'common interfaces' package.

## An Example Concept

I don't want to get too bogged down in domain-level symantics, so I'll use the simple, though slightly contrived, example of an event logger.

#### Package A

Does *XYZ* and allows for a custom logging object to be provided.

To ensure that the logger is valid, Package A contains a `PackageA\Log` interface. When a logging object is provided to the `classX` constructor, it throws an exception if the logger object does not implement `PackageA\Log`.

#### Package B

Does *ABC* and allows for a custom logging object to be provided.

To ensure that the logger is valid, Package B contains a `PackageB\Log` interface. When a logging object is provided to the `classA` constructor, it throws an exception if the logger object does not implement `PackageB\Log`.

#### Package C

A unified logger that provides logging for *Package A* and *Package B*... et al.

Contains `Log` object that is built to provide a generic logger for all packages in the application.

## Current Sub-optimal Ideas:

**1.** Implement neither of the interfaces in the class `PackageC\Log` but extend the class for each interface variation (e.g. `PackageC\Loggers\PackageA` extends `PackageC\Log`).

**Problem:** *Requires more maintenance and means that `PackageC` will have to be modified for every new package that it interfaces with.*

**2.** Implement the interfaces `PackageA\Log` and `PackageB\Log` directly in the class `PackageC\Log`.

**Problem:** *If `PackageC` is re-used in another project, errors will be thrown if either `PackageA` or `PackageB` are not present.*

**3.** Create a Common Interfaces package and have all packages implement/require those interfaces for their public interfaces.

**Problem:** *Massively impractical, would only work for integrating packages that you created; no third party interaction.*

## Question

How can `PackageC\Log` fulfill the requirements of both `PackageA\ClassX` and `PackageB\ClassA`?

In reality this question is usually more complex since the interfaces required by `PackageA` and `PackageB` are probably not the same. So is option 1 (defined above) the only way to solve this? i.e. the package that implements the interface has to write integration classes?

Comment: I think you named all the options. And I think this is "pick your poison" situation. All of the solutions resolve the issue, but each of them has it's problems.

Comment: @Euphoric As I feared; I certainly couldn't think of any other options. Still, it was worth a shot to see if there were any other solutions.

Comment: Does coupling/decoupling apply to packages also? Are we using the clasical meaning of "package" or are we using "package" to signify something different?

Comment: @user61852 Yes, classical meaning of package. e.g. a PHP package imported via composer, or a JS package through bower, etc.

Comment: I thought packages were namespaces/folders.

Comment: @user61852 Terminology varies by language but, in general, Package and Namespace are considered separate but related terms. In PHP a package is always contained within a namespace but a namespace does not necessarily contain a package. A package is a releasable unit of code whilst a namespace is just a logical grouping of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since actual operations for a logging component will be pretty much the same for any other component/class/... that uses it, it makes sense to only offer one interface from Package C.

If Package A and/or Package B require other interfaces for their logging to work, it would make sense to use the [Adapter design pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) to connect the interfaces of `PackageA\Log` to `PackageC\Log` and `PackageB\Log` to `PackageC\Log`.

The interface `PackageC\Log` remains generic, while predefined logging interfaces can be connected to it.

Comment: I've not used the adapter pattern before so please indulge me. If I've understood, I would use `PackageC\Loggers\AdapterA` to imitate `PackageA\Log` and map those `method(parameters)` calls to the correct `method(parameters)` on `PackageC\Log`? If so, is the adapter pattern essentially a formalised version of option 1 in my question?

Comment: You would not insert an adapter inside any of these packages.

An adapter is a piece of code (a component/class/...) that glues two different interfaces with the same intent together, without altering those interfaces (or the package/module/component/class/... it belongs to.)

It may be a simple piece of code that simply takes the arguments from `PackageA\Log` and then calls the coreect interface member in `PackageC\Log`. It could also adjust the parameters if needed (like typeconversions, inserting default values, etc.)

Comment: So all of the packages are unaware of the adapter's existence; the adapter is created by the implementing application, like a specialised piece of wiring logic?

Comment: Exactly. It is part of the plumbing and orchestration of the application.